# off() in jquery to temporary off event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
        $(document).off("click", "#main").on("click", "#main", function () {
            that = $(this);
            $('loading').show();
            Delay = setInterval(function () {
                getMenu(that.attr("menu_id"));
            }, 1000);


        });
```

How can I temporary switch off the event event for #main? because if not #main is clickable during the loading, and caused my function to execute multiple times.

Comment: You could use `$('#main').unbind('click');` to unbind the event and re-bind it with a timer?

Comment: @AlejandroIván `.off` is the replacement for  `.unbind`, just as `.on` replaced `.bind`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I didn't know, I haven't coded in a while :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to make it off like

```
$(document).off("click.main").on("click.main", "#main:not(.disabled)", function () {
    var that = $(this);
    $('loading').show();
    Delay = setInterval(function () {
        getMenu(that.attr("menu_id"));
    }, 1000);
});
```

here if the `#main` has a class called disabled the click handler will not get executed.

So when you want to disable click add the class `disabled` and when you want to enable it back remove the class

Comment: why not $('#main').unbind('click'); and then bind back after done?